# RelativeLayout makes no sense

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I've been working on this layout for about 7 hours today, and that doesn't even count how much time I've put into it this week.
I had posted this earlier today, and since then have progressed immensely.

The goal is to get the `@+id/contactPicture` (the girl) into the `@+id/background`; same thing with the `@+id/myPicture` (me). I'm trying to make it look similar to this (leftmost image): 
[image: cardui]
However, I can't get anything centered and aligned anymore. The `@+id/background` resource is the "card" in this case. I'm not entirely sure what `@+id/holder` does, but I know it is crucial. **Any and all help is appreciated.** Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myPicture"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:maxHeight="48dp"
    android:maxWidth="48dp"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contactPicture"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxHeight="48dp"
    android:maxWidth="48dp"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/body"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/dateColorReceived"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:id="@+id/media"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<View android:layout_below="@+id/media"
      android:id="@+id/gifView"
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gifView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@color/dateColorReceived"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:background="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/myPicture"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactPicture"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorReceived"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="52dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is what my code displays**

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the `@+id/background` is overlapping the contact images. I can't seem to get them into it.

Comment: BTW: RelativeLayout doesn't use android:orientation="vertical".

Answer (score 1):

Later children in a `RelativeLayout` are higher on the Z axis than are earlier children in a `RelativeLayout`. Since your `@+id/background` widget is defined last in the `RelativeLayout`, it will be the highest on the Z axis. For places where your widgets overlap, move their elements in the `<RelativeLayout>` so they are after the widgets they should float on top of and are before the widgets that should float on top of them. I would expect something named `@+id/background` to perhaps be the first widget, so other things float on top of it.

Of course, your pair of empty `LinearLayout` widgets suggest that you may have other problems with this layout. For example, if `@+id/background` is supposed to be the background for something, usually that "something" should be *inside* that `LinearLayout`, instead of being largely disassociated from it.

Comment: Here's the kicker--if I change the `@+id/background` layer to an ImageView, and then proceed to place it at the top of the list--I get the same thing in the screenshot I posted. Nothing is different.

Comment: @Nate: Then use Hierarchy View to determine what is going on.

Comment: Is there anyway I can share this with you?

Comment: @Nate: I do not know what "this" is, sorry.

Comment: What I'm seeing from the HierarchyViewer.

Comment: This is the closest I've been to my desired effect. However, I still never could figure out a way to get the `@+id/body` aligned properly with the contact images (`@+id/contactPicture` and `@+id/myPicture`). [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499800/so-close-to-getting-this-layout-down-relativelayout-linearlayout-woes)

Comment: @Nate: "@JakeWharton FYI, I'm getting a 404 error on your link to the 1.4.1 JAR: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/retrofit/retrofit/1.4.1/retrofit-1.4.1.jar" -- not really. I don't think there's any sort of export option.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider putting both the image and the speech box in a table row. This will make it easier to keep the distance between them.

Comment: How would I go about that? Never used a TableRow before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215909/android-xml-tablerow the question has a good example of how it is used

Comment: @scootie8 But how does the background come into play?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this and hide/show the correct contact picture in my adapter.

You will need to optimize your drawables, backgrounds, colors, fonts, etc. but the idea is a simple layout, should be fast enough. You hide the missing picture (depending who's sending the message) or you can even inflate two layouts (one w/the pic on the left and one on the right) and decide which one to use during the getView… The expensive part is inflating, once you've done that (and have it in a viewholder) then the rest should make your life simpler :)

**note:** I've noticed you want the text to "wrap" the body, so adjust that according to your preference so it looks more like a text "bubble" (like whatsapp).

You will need to tell content layout to wrap_content (remove the weight) and then play with the alignment (left or right) showing and hiding the corresponding picture.

This is how it looks:

[image: layout]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/background_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/row_background"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/medium_gray"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_picture"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:maxHeight="48dp"
        android:maxWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="contact picture" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/contact_name_tv"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:paddingRight="5dp"
          android:ellipsize="marquee"
          android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:text="John Doe"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="12sp" />
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/msg_body"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="this is a sample message…"
          android:ellipsize="marquee"
          android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
          android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:paddingRight="5dp"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="14sp" />
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/msg_date"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="left"
          android:text="5 hours ago"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:paddingRight="5dp"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_picture"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:maxHeight="48dp"
        android:maxWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="contact picture" />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As it turns out, the `TableLayout` seems to bring me the closest to what I'm looking for--it's still not correct though.